# Generically write cases of a function

Tags: haskell

Here is a function:

```
data AnyControlFrame =
   PingFrame_ACF PingFrame
   |SynStream_ACF SynStreamFrame
   |RstStreamFrame_ACF RstStreamFrame
   |SettingsFrame_ACF SettingsFrame
   |WindowUpdateFrame_ACF WindowUpdateFrame
   |Ignored_ACF LB.ByteString


writeControlFrame :: AnyControlFrame -> Put 
writeControlFrame (PingFrame_ACF a)         = put a
writeControlFrame (RstStreamFrame_ACF a)    = put a
writeControlFrame (SettingsFrame_ACF a)     = put a
writeControlFrame (WindowUpdateFrame_ACF a) = put a
....
```

and the cases keep coming. Is there a way to write this function "generically", that is, to abstract over all the cases?

EDIT: The constructors are parametrized with concrete, but different types. I reckon that I may have got something wrong with this "design".... if so, please point it out!

Comment: What's the type of `put`?

Comment: There may exist more "generic" solutions, but they will be longer and more tricky than what you've got. If you had many types like `AnyControlFrame` for which you wanted to generate `write` functions, one could use some Template Haskell to generate them. But for just one type with six constructors, it seems not worth it.

Comment: @chi I agree with you: Generics would be overkill here... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Are you defining `AnyControlFrame` yourself? If so then you can do this:

```hs
data AnyControlFrame = PingFrame_ACF         { someValue :: SomeDataType }
                     | RstStreamFrame_ACF    { someValue :: SomeDataType }
                     | SettingsFrame_ACF     { someValue :: SomeDataType }
                     | WindowUpdateFrame_ACF { someValue :: SomeDataType }
                     | ....

writeControlFrame :: AnyControlFrame -> Put
writeControlFrame = put . someValue
```

This works because the type of `someValue` is `AnyControlFrame -> SomeDataType` and the type of `put` is `SomeDataType -> Put`. Hence you can compose them.

If you are not defining `AnyControlFrame` yourself then the only other thing that (I believe) you can do is define `someValue` yourself:

```hs
someValue :: AnyControlFrame -> SomeDataType
writeControlFrame (PingFrame_ACF a)         = a
writeControlFrame (RstStreamFrame_ACF a)    = a
writeControlFrame (SettingsFrame_ACF a)     = a
writeControlFrame (WindowUpdateFrame_ACF a) = a
....

writeControlFrame :: AnyControlFrame -> Put
writeControlFrame = put . someValue
```

Either way, using `someValue :: AnyControlFrame -> SomeDataType` makes your code more “generic” (although that's not the word I would use to describe it). If you want to write several functions like `writeControlFrame` then using `someValue` makes it much easier.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little confused. Does `someValue` on first solution is really `AnyControlFrame -> SomeDataType`? I think there are 4 different `someValue`'s there(`PingFrame_ACF -> SomeDataType`, `RstStreamFrame_ACF -> SomeDataType`, ...), and their names would clash and this won't compile. Can you explain it to me?

Comment: @utdemir This answer was given before I wrote the type of AnyControlFrame in my question.... if that's worth something...

Comment: @dsign It can't be absolutely heterogeneous if you want to do something "generic" with them. For example, if the type of `put` is `Frame a => a -> Put` then you can just modify the type of `someValue` to `Frame a => AnyControlFrame -> a` and it will still work.

Comment: @dsign What's the type of the `put` function?